# nginx - phpMyAdmin on all server blocks

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to configure nginx so that all server blocks (virtual hosts) goes to phpMyAdmin when specified?

Here's what I want to do:

**www.example1.com/phpmyadmin** goes to phpmyadmin

**www.example2.com/phpmyadmin** goes to the same.

I have this currently working by creating a softlink to the phpMyAdmin directory on ALL server blocks, however I want this to be automatically done to all server blocks and all the new one's that I'll add through a global configuration. Is this possible?

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ /usr/share/nginx/www/example1.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'll need to write it in each server block, the only way to kinda centralize it is to write the location in a separate file and include it in each server block

```
# /etc/nginx/phpmyadmin.conf
location /phpmyadmin {
  alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
}
```

and the virtual host

```
server {
  server_name example.com;
  root /whatever/path;
  location / {
    # whatever conf;
  }
  location ~ \.php$ {
    #php config
  }
  include /etc/nginx/phpmyadmin.conf;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add the following part to the server {} container:

```
location /phpmyadmin {
               root /usr/share/;
               index index.php index.html index.htm;
               location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                       try_files $uri =404;
                       root /usr/share/;
                       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                       fastcgi_index index.php;
                       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                       include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
               }
               location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                       root /usr/share/;
               }
        }
        location /phpMyAdmin {
               rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
        }
```

fastcgi_pass may also be `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;`
it should be same as in ~ .php${...}